# java: copy files without slowing down the system

Tags: java

I have a java program(for personal usage only) that copies a lot of files(using `Files.copy()`). I want to run this program with an executable jar file.

Now, I don't want it to slow down the system. Can I somehow do it with low priority? Either by wrapping the code somehow or by running the jar-file with a cmd-script or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven’t tried this, but I imagine if you avoided using Files.copy and wrote your own copy method that copies, say, 16 bytes at a time, sleeping a second or two between each such transfer, the impact on system performance would be small to negligible.  Using one of the transfer* methods of [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) instead of InputStreams and OutputStreams might also help.

Comment: I don't know of anything you can do within Java itself to cause your code to run at a lower priority than other processes outside the JVM. Lowering your `Files.copy()` thread's priority would only be advisory, and even then would only be relative to other threads within the JVM. Still, it's a good question, and I don't understand why it's getting downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

To launch the Java process with a different priority, you need to use the OS command - for example, in Linux, you use the nice command and in Windows, you use the wmic command. Java itself does not have facilities to change the process priority (only thread priority)

Comment: can i use that to start the jar file in low prio using a cmd-script?

Comment: Yes, launch via  nice -10 java -jar yourjar.jar for example.